# Capture video/image using user's webcam using GWT

Tags: html, gwt, html5-video, webcam

I am developing project using GWT2.5 and I need to use the User’s webcam to capture 
images/video.
How it is possible in GWT?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GWT 2.5 comes with a new library called [Elemental](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/elemental), it is thought as a wrapper of the browser API. It just works with chrome, but in a future it could support more browsers.

If you are confortable supporting in your app chrome for this feature, you can take a look to [this example](http://www.jooink.com/experiments/ElementalGetUserMediaDemo/). The source code of the demo is in [googlecode](https://code.google.com/p/elemental-getusermedia-demo/).

If you wanted to support other browsers, you could take the elemental classes as base and modify them to match other browsers.

Here is a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VOf27ez_Hvg) introducing elemental during the google I/O 2012

Comment: webcame video/audio capturing working properly in chrome. but is there any way for firefox and IE?

Comment: It seems FF 1.6+ supports `getUserMedia()`, proly you could copy some clases from the elemental packages and modify them to work with FF. I think IE10 does not have it, but I've read that IE11 would have it.

Comment: The link 'this example' is giving `404 Not Found` error.

Comment: It seems the live example does not work anymore, here you have the source code, https://code.google.com/p/elemental-getusermedia-demo

Answer (score 0):

A [GWT based API to capture webcam snapshots](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-webcam/) from the browser. This API is a GWT wrapper for the jpegcam JavaScript library.

[Samples and Source code.](http://gwt-webcam.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/)

Hope that helps.